# Error [IM002] on unixODBC FreeTDS

Tags: microsoft, sql

I'm trying to query a SQL Server DB using unixODBC FreeTDS and `isql`

I'm getting the error:

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

when i type odbcinst i get:

```
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /home/pmattos/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /home/pmattos/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /home/pmattos/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/pmattos/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

if i type `cat /home/pmattos/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[dbserverdsn]
        Driver = FreeTDS
        Server = 10.23.11.10
        Port = 1433
        Database=Market
        TDS_Version = 7.2
```

if i type `cat /home/pmattos/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[FreeTDS]
        Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
        Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

And my FreeTDS file looks like this:

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version, use:
    # 7.3 for SQL Server 2008 or greater (tested through 2014)
    # 7.2 for SQL Server 2005
    # 7.1 for SQL Server 2000
    # 7.0 for SQL Server 7
    tds version = 7.2
    port = 1433
    text size = 64512

# A typical Microsoft server
[dbserverdsn]
    host = 10.23.11.10
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.2
```

it's worth saying that I'm able to query the DB using `tsql`.
also sending the command `tsql -LH serverName` doesn't return a thing.

using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
```

Any thoughts on what I might be missing ?

Comment: What OS and version are you running?

Comment: I added the answer on the question ! Ubuntu 14.04.2, thanks